# Has anyone made a DIY Shepherd's Hook?

Tags: container-gardening

I was thinking of getting some shepherd's hooks and was wondering if anyone has come up with any cheaper DIY solutions that might be interesting.

I found some flimsy plans that were mainly used as decoration temporarily. I'm planning on using mine throughout the season to hold hanging planters that can get heavy.

They're only about $7 for 48" ones but I was wondering if I could make my own cheaper, taller and stronger somehow.

Here's an example of what a commercial one with a hanging basket looks like. Found it online at http://portuguese.alibaba.com/product-gs/park-hanging-flower-basket-shepherd-hook-1917181848.html

[image]

Comment: Picture of what you want? I can't imagine how you'd hang a plant with the traditional one-ended hook...

Comment: Ah, an iron plant hanger misnomered as a wooden sheep control device. When going for direct replacement it's too often the case that even if you have the bending stuff (which can be fabricated if you don't) it's not uncommon for the domestically sourced raw straight stock to cost more than the imported complete product. How do you feel about conduit or rebar? Have you got welding tools/ability?

Comment: No good bending tools no welding tools or ability. You're right rebar wouldn't be much cheaper. Conduit would but I can't think of a good design without a conduit bender. I think I have some sand. If I can make a 90 at the top then cut a notch to hold the hanger that could work and be simple.

Comment: Refresh your memory (if needed) on what several variants of conduit bender look like (including what they look like without a handle) and wander by a few yard sales. Odds are good there will be one in the "random tools nobody knows what to do with" pile at a low, low price.